# Converting C++ for loop python

Tags: python, c++, loops

Tried searching around for a similar question, but was unable to solve this. Not sure how to properly convert some of the features in C++ loops. Especially the `count < 20` condition in `main()`.

Original question: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Anti-primes

```cc
#include <iostream>

int countDivisors(int n) {
    if (n < 2) return 1;
    int count = 2; // 1 and n
    for (int i = 2; i <= n/2; ++i) {
        if (n%i == 0) ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    int maxDiv = 0, count = 0;
    std::cout << "The first 20 anti-primes are:" << std::endl;
    for (int n = 1; count < 20; ++n) {
        int d = countDivisors(n);
        if (d > maxDiv) {
            std::cout << n << " ";
            maxDiv = d;
            count++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My attempted solution:

```py
def countDivisors(n):
    if (n < 2):
        return 1
    count = 2

    for i in range(2, int(n/2)-1, 1):
        print(i)    
        if(n%i == 0):
            count = count + 1
    return count

def main():
    print("The first 20 anti-primes are: ")
    n = 1
    while count < 20:    
        d = countDivisors(n)
        if(d > maxDiv):
            print(n)
            maxDiv = d
            count += 1
            n += 1
    return 0
```

Required answer:

```
1 2 4 6 12 24 36 48 60 120 180 240 360 720 840 1260 1680 2520 5040 7560
```

Comment: You reference maxDiv too early. What is initial value for maxDiv?

Comment: 0. i actually initialized maxDiv and count to 0, but i removed it before i posted here.

Comment: Made a few edits to original question

Comment: Do your best to avoid thinking in C++ when writing Python code. Logic may be logic, but how best to implement logic in the two languages is very, very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking about the two `for` loops:

> ```
> for (int i = 2; i <= n/2; ++i)
> ```

would become

```
for i in range(2,int(n/2)+1):
```

The `int(n/2)-1` in your code would be `i < n/2-1` in C.

---

The 20 one,

> ```
> int maxDiv = 0, count = 0;    // <-- !
> for (int n = 1; count < 20; ++n) {
>     int d = countDivisors(n);
>     if (d > maxDiv) {
>         std::cout << n << " ";
>         maxDiv = d;
>         count++;
>     }
> ```

is almost there, just you do not have `maxDiv` and `count` initialized in the Python one.

```
maxDiv = 0  # <-- !
count = 0   # <-- !
n = 1
while count < 20:    
    d = countDivisors(n)
    if(d > maxDiv):
        print(n)
        maxDiv = d
        count += 1
    n += 1
```

Comment: Your translation of the second loop is wrong.  The original one in C++ will loop more than 20 times, and break when`count`, not `i` has reached 20.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica true, I was focusing on the other loop.

Comment: @StormClaw: I do not want to edit it again, but the `n += 1` part was an "autocorrect" without commenting: so in the question it was "too indented" and thus part of the `if`, not the `while`. Then it works, see https://ideone.com/48bWNu

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. Does this yield the result you're looking for?

```
def countDivisors(n):
    if (n < 2):
        return 1
    count = 2

    for i in range(2, int(n/2)-1, 1):
        print(i)    
        if(n%i == 0):
            count = count + 1
    return count

def main():
        print("The first 20 anti-primes are: ")
        n,maxDiv = 1,0
        for d in range(1,20):    
            d = countDivisors(n)
            print(d)
            if(d > maxDiv):
                maxDiv = d
            n+=1
        return 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: tried it, didnt work out of the box. I'll take a closer look later to see if any small changes could possibly fix it.

Comment: added it in question, along with original question

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally the C `for` loop and the Python `for` loop are different.  You have two choices.

The first choice is to do as you did, and use a Python `while` loop to replicate the test-and-stop part of the C `for` loop.  If you do this, you have to write out the iteration yourself.

The second choice is to use a Python `for` loop to replicate the iteration, and write out the test-and-stop part of the code.

```
import itertools
.
.
.
        for n in itertools.count(1):    
            d = countDivisors(n)

            if(d > maxDiv):
                print(n)
                maxDiv = d
                count += 1
                if count >= 20:
                    break
```

I *think* I prefer this form, but it is very much a matter of taste.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using libraries preferably hence why i'm using the while method. It's getting late here, so i'm gonna take another crack at this tomorrow. Mabye someone will come up with a solution by then.

Answer (score 0):

I use a map function within `countDivisors`.

```
def countDivisors(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return 2 + sum(map(lambda x: 0 if n % x else 1, range(2, int(n / 2) + 1)))


def main():
    max_div = 0
    count = 0
    print("The first 20 anti-primes are:")
    x = 1
    while count < 20:
        d = countDivisors(x)
        if d > max_div:
            print(x, end=' ')
            max_div = d
            count += 1
        x += 1
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDLboQgGIX3PsXJJI2QsananRm76iN0T2jBDomgAZzSp7d4r@wO/@07p//19868jqOQDb66wfh39VCus44YWiWITzUwuKFc1PSs9IM1KJJ/osQVbtBE8560XH8KjlAhX6afECBbJ1FksNx8S1JmUMYTgxeUNI4WlNIkSSYKzZUh623NAxPqgRr5rGfCXfV22nH5uEs0yjqPMgc3Xj3HgpYO3MrqQufWEIcW3p@7auW6KLrKD1si9pwjCHQvRh8CbxvQMXRwhAzSiDpFSk/Vw4M4/S8I141rodzlGmseQ4mnGTNcS8ZQ10gZmyJiLN0ymvIaxz8)

Output:

```
The first 20 anti-primes are:
1 2 4 6 12 24 36 48 60 120 180 240 360 720 840 1260 1680 2520 5040 7560
```